# Sorting superclass which has access to ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Hi guys trying to access the super class from a subclass and I have to add a instance of  to the ArrayList, I am trying to sort the super class instance but I wont let me do this.

```
public class Basket extends ArrayList<Product> implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
  private int    theOrderNum = 0;          // Order number

  /**
   * Constructor for a basket which is
   *  used to represent a customer order/ wish list
   */
  public Basket()
  {
    theOrderNum  = 0;
  }
}
```

The subclass I am using is below, I have tried the collections.sort shown below underneath the super.add but for some reason it will not let me access the super class, here is what I have tried.

```
public class BetterBasket extends Basket implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      @Override
      public boolean add( Product pr )    // Add a product to the
      {             
          super.add(pr);
          Collections.sort(super, super.get(0).getProductNum());    

      }
}
```

I am trying to sort it by the product number stored in the super class, shown in the first example.

Comment: Use this instead of super.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply refer to `this` object since it already extends `ArrayList` and holds the elements that you added using `super.add(pr)` and that you want to sort:

```
Collections.sort(this, ....
```

The second parameter should be a `Comparator` implementation, and not the first element in the list.

```
Collections.sort(this, new Comparator<Product>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
            return p1.getProductNum() - p2.getProductNum();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Collection.sort()` method expects either a collection of objects that implement Comparable, or a collection of objects and a Comparator object that allows comparing them.

So you can't just pass it an integer as the second parameter.

You need to read up on the `Comparator` and build a `Comparator` that knows how to compare two `Product` objects, or write `Product` so that it implements `Comparable`.

One other thing is that you cannot access a `private` member of your superclass from a subclass. This is a very basic concept in Object Oriented Programming. You can only access its protected, public, or package-accessible fields.

If you do have visible (protected/public/package-accessible) field, you don't need to use the `super` keyword to access it, because the idea of extending a class is that you inherit its behavior and its state, so if a field is visible, you can just access it by its name or `this`.name.

You need to use the `super` keyword only if you need to access methods that you have overridden in your subclass, or fields that you have hidden (which you shouldn't do anyway).